# Exception while deploying the app on Sun Glassfish Enterprise Server V3

Tags: java, jsf-2, spring-security, glassfish-3

I am using spring framework version 3.1 anf jsf 2.0. When I try to deploy war file on Sun Glassfish Enterprise Server V3, I am getting very weird error at deploy time.

**Exception while deploying the app : java.lang.RuntimeException: WEB9033: Unable to load  class with name [org.springframework.security.annotation.Jsr250MethodDefinitionSource], reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/intercept/method/AbstractFallbackMethodDefinitionSource**

Comment: Check that you have put all the jars in your project classpath (or in the pom if you're using maven).

Comment: I already checked that and same war file is perfectly working on Jetty server

Comment: Maybe you have additional spring jars in your Jetty server. Check the jar were this spring class belongs and check if your war contains it.

Comment: WAR file contains spring-security-core 3.1.0 jar which is need for AbstractFallbackMethodDefinitionSource class

Comment: Undeploy the WAR, restart GlassFish and try deploying it one more time. If this is unsuccessful, there's no more than report it to GlassFish guys. I'm still thinking your war doesn't have the jar in the classpath or maybe you're trying to deploy the wrong war.

Comment: I checked everything 3 times. WAR file contains all jar files required and I deployed that WAR file on other pc as well. Problem still persist....

Comment: Also try to see if multiple copies of that jar exist within the app server's reach/Classpath. Multiple copies of a jar might be confusing the Classloader for your app (as is the case with tomcat)

Comment: I checked everything regarding jar files.... Still no improvement